# Php to query sidebar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am starting a website and can query all my products in the table to display on my page. In the left sidebar it also displays the color and price like this

> COLOR
>
> yellow (3)
>
> white (9)
>
> tan (1)
>
> red (3)
>
> purple (1)
>
> pink (7)
>
> orange (1)
>
> multi (1)
>
> green (8)
>
> brown (1)
>
> blue (3)
>
> black (3)
>
> PRICE
>
> Under $25 (4)
>
> $25-$50 (4)
>
> 2/$40 (22)
>
> 2/$50 (10)
>
> 3/$33 (1)

So I used COUNT and GROUP BY to display it like this. What I want to click on one of the colors or one of the prices and it will narrow the products down. So say I click on black I want it to be able to query just the 3 black products

Here is my php for the all the products in the table

```
  <?php
$dynamicList ="";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test2 LIMIT");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
 if ($productCount > 0) {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $product_name = $row["product_name"];
      $image_url = $row["image_url"];
      $category = $row["category"];
      $subcategory = $row["subcategory"];
      $sub_subcategory = $row["sub_subcategory"];
      $price = $row["price"];
      $color = $row["color"];
      $page_url = $row["page_url"];
    $dynamicList .= '<div id="products">

  <table width="24%" height="339" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
  <td height="150" align="center" valign="bottom"><a href="'.$page_url.'"     target="_blank"><img src="'.$image_url.'" Hspace="5" Vspace="10" width="140" height="210" /></a></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="90" align="center" valign="top"><p><a href="'.$page_url.'" target="_blank">'.$product_name.'<br /><b><font size="3"><font color="#FF0000">'.$price.'</font> </font></b></a></p></td>
   </tr>
  </table></div>';


}
} else {
$dynamicList = "<b>There are currently no items</b>";
 }
?>
```

And this is the php for for the color and price that display on the left sidebar which I want to be able to link

```
<?php echo 
$sidebar_color ="";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *,COUNT(color) FROM test2 GROUP BY color ORDER BY color         DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($productCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

   $color = $row["color"];

    $sidebar_color .= '<div id="sidebar"><p><font size="-2"><a   href="index.php?'.$color.'">'.$color.' ('.$row["COUNT(color)"].')</a>
                    </font></p></div>';
}
}
?>
 <?php echo 
$sidebar_price ="";
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT *,COUNT(sidebar) FROM test2 GROUP BY price ORDER BY price ASC");
  $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
 if ($productCount > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $price = $row["price"];

    $sidebar_price .= '<div id="price"><p><font size="-2"><a href="index.php?'.$price.'">'.$price.' ('.$row["COUNT(price)"].')</a>
            </font></p></div>';
}
}
?>
```

---

Hi Bryan thanks for the comment. I wasn't able to get it to work. It kept coming up with error. Also this is the code for it displayed on my page

```
<div id="side"
 <ul>
 <p>_____________</p>
 <p><font size="3"><b>COLOR</b></font></p>
 <font size="-2"><li><?php echo $sidebar_color; ?></li>
 </font></ul>

  <ul>
 <p>_____________</p>
 <p><font size="3"><b>PRICE</b></font></p>
 <font size="-2"><li><?php echo $sidebar_price; ?></li>
 </font></ul>


 </div>
  </td>


  <td width="80%" valign="top"><p>

  <?php echo $dynamicList; ?><br />


  </p></td>
```

So when I click on say black again I need to display the $dynamicList but just with the products that are black.

I hope this all makes sense to you. I am very new at this. So any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there are price for anyone answering this ?

Answer (score 1):

replace this line(same with price)

```
<a href="index.php?'.$color.'">
```

with

```
<a href="index.php?color='.$color.(isset($_GET['price'])?'&price='.$_GET['price']: '').'">
```

then you can use $_GET['color'] and $_GET['price'] to set up your query to display products ie...

```
$options = array();
(isset($_GET['price']) ? $options[] = "price='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['price'])."'" : '' );
(isset($_GET['color']) ? $options[] = "color='" mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['color'])."'" : '' );
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $options);
```

also an FYI mysql functions should be replaced with [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).